# Java client program to consume REST call with authorization

Tags: java, rest, client, consumer

I need to invoke a REST call from Java code.

I have credentials in the form of

1. Id
2. Security Key

An algorithm provided which

1. Gets the server time
2. Using Id,  security key  &  server time it generates a security token

Now authorization  is in the below form

```
"Authorization": "name id=Id, serverTime=serverTime, securitytoken=securitytoken"
```

Need a java client program to invoke this REST call using above authorization header.

I am getting

> HTTP Response 401 error.

Please provide correct way to set authorization header in request for form

```
Name Id="Id",serverTime="2017-11-18T05:51:05",securityToken="TOKEN"
```

Code:

```
package com.rest.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.URL;

public class Sample {

    public final static String GATEWAY_ID = "Id";

    public final static String KEY = "Key";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn;

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://domain/A/B/72968").openConnection();

            String serverTime = "2017-11-18T10:51:05";

            String securityToken = "TOKEN"; 

            String authorization = "Name Id=\"" + GATEWAY_ID + "\",serverTime=\"" + serverTime + "\",securityToken=\""
                    + securityToken + "\"";

            // Name Id="Id",serverTime="2017-11-18T10:51:05",securityToken="TOKEN"

            conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization); // Is Header set is correct? It should be part of Request Header. Please correct this

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();

            System.out.println(status);

            BufferedReader br = null;

            StringBuilder body = null;

            String line = "";

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            body = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                body.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println(body);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://domain/A/B/72968
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>       at com.rest.client.ApplicationClient.main(ApplicationClient.java:48)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://domain/A/B/72968
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>       at com.rest.client.ApplicationClient.main(ApplicationClient.java:38)

Answer (score 1):

try format authorization string this way `"Basic Base64"`. try

```
 authorization ="Basic "+new String(new Base64().encode(authorization.getBytes()));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
```

Comment: Thanks for Comment. Tried this but still got HTTP 401

Comment: So It seems there is a problem with: 
String authorization = "Name Id=\"" + GATEWAY_ID + "\",serverTime=\"" + serverTime + "\",securityToken=\""+ securityToken + "\"";

Comment: It looks like you have just example of authorization string and not an actual parameters to pass the authorization.

Comment: I am replacing with actual parameters before call